# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'import_export'

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I've used the following [tutorial](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html). I used the command 
`pip install django-import-export`, then added to the Installed Apps section.

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'import_export',
    'frontend',
    'userauth',
    'methods',
]
```

When I run `python manage.py collectstatic` I get error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'import_export'`

Comment: If you are using a virtual environments, make sure that you run `pip install` and `manage.py` in the same virtual env.

Answer (score 13):

Install the import_export module by writing this command in command prompt

`pip install --user django-import_export`
or use
`pip install django-import_export`

Comment: Your package name has an underscore. There should be a hyphen instead.

Comment: It worked, but I removed the --user, since the requirements.txt should be for every user

Comment: Yes in my case the command runs with --user and in your case its runs without --user nice.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you used virtual environment to develop some parts of your project (maybe accidentally) and then you switched it off.

Try to reinstall the modules with your virtual environment activated.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same bug before, and here is what I did.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.conf',
'import_export',]
```

Be careful, the order of `'django.conf'` and `'import_export'` cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have installed Django in `virtualenv`. Now when you installed `django-import-export` you forgot to activate your virtual environment. I doubt there is something else.

Also make sure that your virtual environment is enabled when you run `django manage.py collectstatic`. You might have installed Django outside all virtual environments once in the past (by mistake) and is therefore not raising "Django not found" errors but cannot find `import_export` because you actually installed it in virtual environment.

Comment: I am new to django! Can you please explain me how to activate virtualenv

Comment: Are you using virtual environment?

Comment: I've installed virtual environment. But am not using it in my project

Answer (score 0):

**Simple please install**
`django-import-export==2.5.0`

> i hope its work

Answer (score 0):

### Following worked for me, I still don't understand why.

1. Delete your virtual env directory.
   `rm -rf env`
2. Come out of the virtual env.
   `exec $SHELL`
3. Create the virtual environment again.
   `python -m venv env`
4. Activate your virtual env.
   `source ./env/bin/activate`
5. Install the requirements again.
   `pip install -r requirements.txt`

And it worked

Answer (score 0):

to solve this problem you can try by installing `django import-export` only, I tried installing `import-export` which by default is `0.3.1 version` and `django import-export` installs `3.2.0 version` and fixed the problem